# You have a bucket of unfair coins. Calculate the expected value.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have recently found the following question.

"You have a bucket of unfair coins. Each coin has a probability of getting heads, p, which is uniformly distributed between zero and one. You pick a coin, and flip it 64 times, getting 48 heads. What is the expected value of p for your coin?"

I have no idea how to even approach this question. I tried searching for existing versions of it on StackExchange but could not find anything.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: "Each coin has a probability of getting heads, p, which is uniformly distributed between zero and one. " I'm not quite sure what this means. Does it mean, there are $n$ coins and the probability of each coin getting heads is $p_1 = \frac{1}{n},\ p_2=\frac{2}{n},\ \ldots,\ p_n= \frac{n}{n},\ $ repectively?

Comment: @AdamRubinson: I interpret it to mean that each $p_k$ is a uniformly distributed random variable on the interval $[0, 1]$.  You randomly select one coin from the bucket, not knowing either $k$ or $p_k$.

Comment: ...for which the probability of getting exactly 48 heads in 64 flips is ${64 \choose 48}p_k^{48}(1-p_k)^{16}$.

Comment: And the question seems that it's expecting you to use Bayesian inference.

Comment: It is not clear what is the role of the other coins.

Comment: Do you know about Bayes theorem and Bayesian statistics?  Beta distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\mathrm p\sim\mathcal U[0,1]$ and $H\mid\mathrm p\sim\mathcal{Bin}(64,\mathrm p)$ and wish to find: $\mathsf E(\mathrm p\mid H{\,=\,}48)$ .

So : -

$$\mathsf E(\mathrm p\mid H{\,=\,}48) = \dfrac{~~\displaystyle\int_0^1 \rho~\mathsf P(H{\,=\,}48\mid\mathrm p{\,=\,}\rho)\,\mathrm d\rho~~}{\displaystyle\int_0^1 \mathsf P(H{\,=\,}48\mid\mathrm p{\,=\,}\rho)\,\mathrm d\rho} $$

Comment: Yes, that looks like the right answer.
After putting this into Mathematica, the answer turns out to be around 0.75. And that seems to be right, given that 48/64 = 0.75
Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, it is $(48+1)/(64+2)$ actually.  @Mkion57